# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "testing"

Tags: sql, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, psql, ubuntu-18.04

When I run the psql command from the postgres user account like this:

```
sudo -i -u testuser psql testdb -c 'select * from "USER" where "LogInName"='TESTING';'
```

so what can i do for this case thank you for your answer.

Comment: I want to do this also so can you help me:

`sudo -i -u testuser psql testdb -c 'update "USER" set "Password"='testing' where "LogInName"='TESTING.IT';'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use dollar-quoted-string in postgres like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657883/how-do-i-escape-single-quote-in-command-line-query-of-psql)

```
sudo -i -u testuser psql testdb -c 'select * from "USER" where "LogInName"=$$TESTING$$;'
```

Comment: HI Jonathan thank for your answer, but for this not work for me: 
`sudo -i -u testuser psql testdb -c 'select * from "USER" where "LogInName"=$$TESTING.IT$$;'`